# ImportError Python Reportlab

Tags: python, python-2.7

Olá, estou tentando importar a seguinte *lib* em meu projeto Python 2.7:

```
from reportlab.lib.rparsexml import simpleparse
```

Erro:

> ImportError: No module named reportlab.lib.rparsexml

Já tentei instalar o `python-reportlab`:

> python-reportlab is already the newest version.

Obs: estou utilizando o `virtualenv`.

Comment: É provavel que você tenha instalado o reportlab no ambiente virtual mas o seu projeto não está conectado ao virtualenv

Comment: No terminal ative o seu ambiente virtual, digite `python` no terminal e tente importar o módulo `import reportlab`, se importar com sucesso é que o seu projeto não está configurado para rodar no ambiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente esse tipo de erro acontece quando se usa um Python diferente do que o Python no qual foi instalado a lib.

Como você está utilizando *virtualenv*, verifique se o virtualenv do seu projeto está ativado antes de instalar a lib. Quando for executar seu projeto, também confirme que ele será executado com o Python do virtualenv.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda. Encontrei meu erro. O virtualenv estava ativado e funcionando corretamente. O virtualenv não estava conseguindo ver a lib `python-reportlab` pois instalei a mesma com apt-get install.. sendo assim o virtualenv não conseguia ver a lib. Instalei a lib com `pip install reportlab` e funcionou.